# Get a running total from a list

Tags: python

I'm reading in items:

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip()
    data = line.split("-")
```

If I print `data` as it is read, it looks like:

```
['Adam', '5']
['Peter', '7']
['Adam', '8']
['Lucy', '2']
['Peter', '4']
```

How can I get a running total for each unique name, such my new list would look like:

```
['Adam', '13'],
['Peter', '11'],
['Lucy', '2']
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `collections.Counter()` to count the occurrences:

```
import collections

lines = [['Adam', '5'],
         ['Peter', '7'],
         ['Adam', '8'],
         ['Lucy', '2'],
         ['Peter', '4']]

counter = collections.Counter()
for data in lines:
    counter[data[0]] += int(data[1])

print(counter)
```

You'll get:

```
Counter({'Adam': 13, 'Peter': 11, 'Lucy': 2})
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend creating a dictonary and updating that as you go. I have assumed your data format for *data* is a list of lists.

```
finalList = {}

for name, value in data:
    if name in finalList.keys():
        finalList[name] = finalList[name] + int(value)
    else:
        finalList[name] = int(value)

print(finalList)
```

Comment: You may want to cast the value to int - coming from stdin, they would default to char datatypes.

Comment: You have a dict and not a list in the end. You should add something like 'finalList = [(v, k) for k, v in finalList.iteritems()]' in the end

Answer (score 1):

Initialize a `defaultdict` with type int and use the name as the key

```
from collections import defaultdict
name_list = defaultdict(int)
for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip()
    data = line.split("-")
    name = data[0]
    value = int(data[1])
    name_list[name] += value
for key, value in name_list.items(): print key, value
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas does a very good job in handling this kind of situations

```
import pandas as pd
df_data=pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer=path,sep='_',names =['Name','value'])
df=df_data.groupby(['Name'])['value'].sum()

print df
```

output

```
'Adam'     13
'Lucy'      2
'Peter'    11
```

Input file

```
Adam_5
Peter_7
Adam_8
Lucy_2
Peter_4
```