# Grouping common terms in list of tuples and summing associated values

Tags: python

If I have a list like this:

```
[('apple', 5), ('banana', 9), ('apple', 3), ('orange', 1), ('banana', 2)]
```

and I want to output this guy:

```
[('apple', 8), ('banana', 11), ('orange', 1)]
```

what is the smoothest way to do it?

Comment: See [Get a running total from a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41245728/get-a-running-total-from-a-list) (that's a list of lists instead of a list of tuples, but same concept)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use defaultdict(int) or Counter from collections

```
from collections import defaultdict

counts = defaultdict(int)
for fruit, count in fruits:
    counts[fruit] += count
fruit_counts = counts.items()
```

You could also use `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter
for fruit, count in fruits:
    counts[fruit] += count
fruit_counts = counts.most_common()
```

If you need to preserve the original order, you might want to use an OrderedDict:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

counts = OrderedDict()
for fruit, count in fruits:
    counts.setdefault(fruit, 0)
    counts[fruit] += count
fruit_counts = counts.items()
```

I wrote an article with [a number of ways to count items in a list in Python](http://treyhunner.com/2015/11/counting-things-in-python/).

Comment: Then `list(counts.items())` (OP is looking for a list of tuples). Note that the initial order is lost with this method.

Comment: Very good point! I just added an example with OrderedDict in case that's important.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, store the values in a dictionary, accumulating it as you find more of the same key:

```
acc_items = {}

for fruit, count in items:
    # if the fruit is in the dictionary then add count to its value, else the value for fruit is count 
    acc_items[fruit] = acc_items.get(fruit, 0) + count  

print(acc_items.items())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `groupby` from `itertools` with a `dict` like this example:

```
my_list = [('apple', 5), ('banana', 9), ('apple', 3), ('orange', 1), ('banana', 2)]

b = dict()

for k, v in groupby(my_list, lambda x : x[0]):
    try:
        b[k] = b[k] + list(v)[0][1]
    except KeyError:
        b[k] = list(v)[0][1]

final = [(k, v) for k, v in b.items()]
```

Output:

```
print(final)
>>> [('apple', 8), ('banana', 11), ('orange', 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def combine_tuple(list):
    storageArray = []
    for i in list:
        for j in storageArray:
            if j[0] == i[0]:
                j[1] += i[1]
                break
        storageArray.append([[i[0], i[1]])
    return storageArray #this however, actually returns a list of lists, not a list of tuples
```

Comment: About your comment: why not use `.append(([i[0], i[1]))` and return a list of tuples?

Comment: Because in the line `j[1] += i[1]`, as tuples are immutable, it will not work.

Comment: My bad, read too fast.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I cooked up - which to me seems the smoothest. Well... it's at least the shortest and probably quite fast.

```
import pandas as pd
a_agg = [tuple(row) for row in pd.DataFrame(a).groupby(0, as_index=False)[1].sum().values]
```

Thank you for all the input. I was hoping for something pure python (no imports) but the best way in that regard seems to be just using a dictionary.